# [iOS]Choose Image from Photo Gallery

Tags: uiimageview, gallery, photo

I know how to open Photo Gallery , now I want to select one of those images and place it on UIImageView , are there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Did u mention photo gallery means what ?

below one is the code to access image from the photo library

```
-(void)photoLibraryAction
{
    NSLog(@"image");
    if(picker!=nil){
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [test dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        picker.delegate=nil;
        picker=nil;
        test.delegate=nil;
        test=nil;
    }
    picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    picker.delegate=(id)self;

    NSLog(@"%@",picker);
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [self  presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    // [self pre
    else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        UIPopoverController *popImageLibrary=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:picker];
        test=popImageLibrary;
        test.delegate=(id)self;

        [test presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(240, 730, 400, 0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    }

}
```

And set the delegate for the image picker

```
picker.delegate=(id)self;
```

then use the delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)albumPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone || albumPicker.sourceType==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        {
            self.imageData=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
                [albumPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
         }
        else
        {
            yourImageView.image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
            [test dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];            

         }

}
```